# Is this evaluation of the limit correct for the following graph?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+}$  $f(f(x))$
[graph http://puu.sh/kPe30/a3712d99f3.png](http://puu.sh/kPe30/a3712d99f3.png)

- As x approaches 0 from the right side, it f(x) approaches 2 from below. So we find evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^-}$  $f(x)$, Which we can see through the graph to be -2.

Is this correct? I am kind of confused on evaluating the limit for a composite function. If this is correct, how would you evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to -3}$  $f(f(x))$

Comment: Your first analysis at 2 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is constant in an open interval about $-3$ and it returns the value $-1$ there, you have

$$\lim_{x\to -3} f(f(x)) = -1$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be DNE because lim x --> -3 f(x) = 2 , and lim x -->2 f(x) does not exist?

Comment: or can you just use the limit definition of composite functions since it is continuous about -3? Which will give you -1