# Evaluation of a composite function

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is a question I had posted earlier: [Is this evaluation of the limit correct for the following graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486668/is-this-evaluation-of-the-limit-correct-for-the-following-graph)

How would I evaluate the limit for:

($f(x)$ is in the graph in the link above)

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}f(2\cos x)$

I had thought: 
$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}f(2\cos x) = 2$ , and it approaches from below. So $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^-}f(x) = -2$.

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Sorry i just edited to make it more clear as to what f was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "f"?  If f(x) is continuous at x= 2, then $ \lim_{x\to 0} f(2 cos(x))= f(\lim_{x\to 0} 2 cos(x))= f(2)$.

If f is the function from the previous problem, it is NOT continuous at 2, the limit of f(x) as x goes to does not exist, and this limit does not exist.

Comment: Sorry i just edited to make it more clear as to what f was

Comment: You're almost there! Rather than [math] and [/math], or [tex] and [/tex], it's simply dollar signs: `$\pi r^2$` is used to produce $\pi r^2$.